# Alternate size of a box content using HTML/CSS in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

currently i am using css to alternate colors in each day of a week appointment app, where i will be adding appointments. However, since space in the screen is necessary , i wanted to know if anyone can helpe me make each day of my calendar smaller when no content (appointment) exists. i tried ng-class if statements but no luck. [this is what i have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIKQc.png)

```
 <div ng-repeat="day in days" ng-class-odd="'mask'" ng-class-even="'day'" >
```

the frist picture is what i have now, and the second is the sizing that i desired to accomplish when no content is in each day.

[desired prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isfk0.png)

Comment: Update your  question with HTML/CSS

Answer (score 0):

Ng-class should work for what you are trying to achieve.
It should look something like this:

```
 <div ng-repeat="day in days" ng-class="{'css-class': day.isEmpty}">
```